# How to Extract title from <a> tag within DIV using Python?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, title

I am new to Python,
I want to extract all the title/s inside < a > tags that are placed in Divs.
it could have 0 title or as many as 100.

it is the child DIV `<div class="Shl zI7 iyn Hsu">` that contains < a > tag and title in it.

this is the first Main DIV code that contains all child DIV in it:

```
<div class="Eqh F6l Jea k1A zI7 iyn Hsu"><div class="Shl zI7 iyn Hsu"><a data-test-id="search-guide" 
href="" title="Search for &quot;living room colors&quot;"><div class="Jea Lfz XiG fZz gjz qDf zI7 iyn 
Hsu" style="white-space: nowrap; background-color: rgb(162, 152, 139);"><div class="tBJ dyH iFc MF7 
erh tg7 IZT mWe">Living</div></div></a>
```

in the above example, I want to get the "living room colors" not everything in front of title=,
I guess I could have some RegEx later, but I have the problem of getting the title from HTML parsing.

I have tried the following Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=room%20color"
get_url = requests.get(url)
get_text = get_url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, "html.parser")
DivTitle = soup.select('a.Shl.zI7.iyn.Hsu')[0].text.strip()
print(DivTitle)
```

I get:  IndexError: list index out of range

as I search the above keyword, there is more than one title ( suggestion keywords) that appears in the search result.

appreciate your help.

EDITED:
OK, I got this working, but I am trying to make it work parsing from URL instead of pasting my code:

here is the part that I used:

```
import requests
vgm_url = 'https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=skin%20care'
html_text = requests.get(vgm_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
```

but I get nothing, no error either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong as the DIV has the classes you want and the A is a child of that DIV. `title` is an attribute of the A element.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Eqh F6l Jea k1A zI7 iyn Hsu">
      <div class="Shl zI7 iyn Hsu">
        <a data-test-id="search-guide" href="" title="Search for &quot;living room colors&quot;">
          <div class="Jea Lfz XiG fZz gjz qDf zI7 iyn Hsu" style="white-space: nowrap; background-color: rgb(162, 152, 139);">
            <div class="tBJ dyH iFc MF7 erh tg7 IZT mWe">Living</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

a = soup.select('div.Shl.zI7.iyn.Hsu a')[0]

print(a['title'])
```

Comment: soup.select returns an iterable. Remove the [0] at the end then loop. I.e., `for a in soup.select(...):`

Comment: thanks for the response, since I could not make it work it using URL, I copied the whole html code and tried it:  a = soup.select('div.Eqh.F6l.Jea.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu a')
for a in soup.select(...):
   print(a['title'])   but I get this error:AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: You we're supposed to replace the 3 dots with the value from my answer. I am on my phone and cannot do it for you.

Comment: thanks for the response, now it is working, I used: for a in soup.select('div.Eqh.F6l.Jea.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu a'):

Comment: How can I parse it from the URL instead of pasting my HTML code? I have tried with request.get but I get nothing, no error either, thanks.

Comment: I updated my post, added the code that I tried to parse from the URL,

Comment: Looks like pinterest.com loads the content using javascript, thus you'll need something that executes javascript such as Selenium. Have a go at using Selenium then create a **new** post when you have problems.